# A very long gps location search

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm writing an app which gets user location with GPS. I added permission to manifest `(android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)`, asked for required runtime permissions and made my app start searching, but this search can take a very long time (about 5 minutes) or last forever not returning any result. But the original Google Maps application determines my location instantly, so the problem is not in the GPS. Maybe someone knows what the problem is?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_GPS = 0;

LocationManager manager;

private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            String lathitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Your Location is - \nLat: " + lathitude + "\nLong: " + longitude,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry, location unavailable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            findGPSLocation();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_GPS) {
        // Request for camera permission.
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission has been granted.
            startGPSSearch();
        } else {
            // Permission request was denied.
        }
    }
}

private void findGPSLocation() {
    // Check if the Camera permission has been granted
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is already available
        startGPSSearch();
    } else {
        // Permission is missing and must be requested.
        requestPermission();
    }
}

private void requestPermission() {
    // Permission has not been granted and must be requested.
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_GPS);
}

private void startGPSSearch() {
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request a GPS location, this means android is waiting for a GPS fix from satelites. If you test your code inside building this might not be possible, or might take longer time. Google maps is (most probably) using fused location api which makes use of many different sources of location - but it provides an accurracy of the location so you can make your mind if accurracy is enough for your needs (google maps shows this accurracy with larger / smaller circle around your position).

To use fused location api start here: https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/

You may request network location updates by adding :

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies